# MySQL to filter result by using where & and condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to fetch some rows from a question table in MySQL like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM raise_question 
where  documentID = '1' 
   and delReq != 1 OR delReq IS NULL
```

However, some rows have different `documentID`. (Please see the picture). Is this a correct way (using `HAVING` instead of `AND`) to return the result I want ( which is it only contains specific `documentID`):

```
SELECT * 
FROM raise_question 
where  documentID = '1' 
having delReq != 1 OR delReq IS NULL
```

With AND query returns:
[image]

The expected result (only contains one documentID) after using Having I want is like this:
[image]

Comment: No, this is not correct.  You should be using `HAVING` with `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` translate to

```
where  (documentID = '1' 
   and delReq != 1) OR delReq IS NULL
```

, because `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`
Put bracket in your `OR` statement.

```
where  documentID = '1' 
   and (delReq <> 1 OR delReq IS NULL)
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you so much! It make a lot scenes. Looks like I get the same result when I use Having instead of bracket. Can I ask why using Having is not good?

Comment: `HAVING` is meant to be used with `GROUP BY`.  If there's no `GROUP BY`, using `HAVING` will not make sense.  Google `HAVING` to find out more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select distinct documentid
from raise_question
where delReq <> 1 or delReq is null;
```

This returns document ids that have a non-1 `delreq` value.

Comment: Hi Gordon,  I think I need the records for all columns but only under one documentID, is this possible?